# Select/Highlight Columns in Excel 2010 Based on Their Addresses

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in Excel which contains the addresses of the cells that need to be selected and then highlighted. Please find below a snapshot:

```
Col#   Row#     Corresponding Address 
8      1        $H$1
9      2        $I$2
10     3        $J$3
10     4        $J$4
9      5        $I$5
10     6        $J$6
10     7        $J$7
10     8        $J$8
11     9        $K$9
12     10       $L$10
12     11       $L$11
11     12       $K$12
```

As an example, I need to select  cell $H$1 and highlight it.

I would like to perform this task automatically for a large matrix. What would the vba code be for this task?

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to loop through the `Corresponding Address` column and set, (assuming that you want the cell colour changed in order to highlight it) the `Interior.Colour` to a RGB value:

```
Dim x As Worksheet, y As Worksheet
Dim CtrA As Long
Set x = Worksheets("SheetName1")
Set y = Worksheets("SheetName2")
For CtrA = 2 To x.Rows.Count
    y.Range(x.Range("C" & CtrA)).Interior.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
Next
```

where `x` is a reference to the sheet containing the table in your question, and `y` is a reference to the sheet that contains the cells you want to highlight.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code is performing the required task; however, I received the following error message upon executing the code: Run-Time Error '1004': Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed. Can you elaborate on this issue? Thank you again!

Comment: You would need to be more specific; what line and in what circumstances?